# Wordpress masonry and infinite scroll not working

Tags: wordpress, scroll, infinite, masonry, imagesloaded

I have been trying to implement masonry and infinite scroll for a few weeks now but I just can't get it to work properly.

I have used this script: https://gist.github.com/kunalnagar/8232647

My code can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/d6YPupNz

I have called both Masonry and ImagesLoaded in the header:

```
  <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

  <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? I'm new to developing and at a complete loss now.

Many thanks

Comment: Can't you provide an url to the website? I need some more information to figure out what's the cause...

Comment: Unfortunately it's being developed locally, otherwise I would have shared the link right away.

I think I've given up now and trying another approach using JScroll. I have masonry working on all posts using this method.